# How to handle multiple associated log messages?

Tags: sql, logging, hive, analytics, pivot-table

I have a service that calculates a bunch of things for a project. A user can trigger this calculation multiple times a day. Every calculation generates a few interesting metrics (let's call them A, B, C).

I report these metrics to a log service with individual log messages. The log messages look like this:

```
date  |  calculationID1  |  projectID1  |  metricA  |  valueA
date  |  calculationID1  |  projectID1  |  metricB  |  valueB
date  |  calculationID1  |  projectID1  |  metricC  |  valueC
date  |  calculationID2  |  projectID2  |  metricA  |  valueA
date  |  calculationID2  |  projectID2  |  metricB  |  valueB
date  |  calculationID2  |  projectID2  |  metricC  |  valueC
date  |  calculationID3  |  projectID1  |  metricA  |  valueA
date  |  calculationID3  |  projectID1  |  metricB  |  valueB
date  |  calculationID3  |  projectID1  |  metricC  |  valueC
```

In this example the project with ID 1 was run two times on this particular day. In my analytics backend I have a Hive cluster to analyze this data and I want to generate a table with the last reported metrics for every project for a given day day:

```
date  |  calculationID3  |  projectID1  |  valueA  |  valueB  |  valueC
date  |  calculationID2  |  projectID2  |  valueA  |  valueB  |  valueC
```

Apparently this calculation is really costly as I do a lot of joins. My company has a strict logging format and that's why I created one value per log message. Should I create one log message containing all metrics instead to ease the reporting?

Can anyone point me to best practices for these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

If we use DB, supporting [PIVOT clause](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) in SQL, then we can gather data from log report using the following query.

The same results can be fetched without `PIVOT`, but another way requires a lot of copy-paste and juggling, and since you are ["pragmatic with implementation"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353652/lars-schneider), I suppose we don't need to speak about those dirty things.

To see what's happening in the query you can do 3 steps:

- run the query without `PIVOT` (just remove the `PIVOT` keyword and the rest of the code)
- then run it as is
- compare results of the first and the second step, recognising how the rows are transposing to the columns

---

```
WITH
  data_table (stamp, calculation_ID, project_ID, metric_name, metric_value) as ( select

      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:01', 'calc_ID_1', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_A', 11 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:02', 'calc_ID_1', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_B', 21 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:03', 'calc_ID_1', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_C', 31 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:04', 'calc_ID_2', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_A', 12 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:05', 'calc_ID_2', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_B', 22 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:06', 'calc_ID_2', 'project_WHITE', 'metric_C', 32 from dual union all select

      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:11', 'calc_ID_3', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_A', 41 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:12', 'calc_ID_3', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_B', 51 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:00:13', 'calc_ID_3', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_C', 61 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:14', 'calc_ID_4', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_A', 42 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:15', 'calc_ID_4', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_B', 52 from dual union all select
      timestamp '2015-01-01 00:01:16', 'calc_ID_4', 'project_BLACK', 'metric_C', 62 from dual       
  )
SELECT *
  FROM (
      select trunc(stamp) AS day,
             calculation_id,
             project_id,
             metric_name,
             metric_value
       from (
         select t.*,
                rank() OVER (PARTITION BY project_ID, metric_name, trunc(stamp) ORDER BY stamp DESC) calculation_rank
         from data_table t
        -- take only the last log row for (project_ID, metric_name) for every given day
      ) where calculation_rank = 1
)
PIVOT (
  -- aggregate function is required here,
  -- and SUM can be replaced with something more relevant to custom logic
  SUM(metric_value)
  FOR
  metric_name IN ('metric_A' AS "Metric A",
                  'metric_B' AS "Metric B",
                  'metric_C' AS "Metric C")
);
```

Results:

```
 DAY        | CALCULATION_ID | PROJECT_ID    | Metric A | Metric B | Metric C
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2015-01-01 | calc_ID_4      | project_BLACK | 42       | 52       | 62
 2015-01-01 | calc_ID_2      | project_WHITE | 12       | 22       | 32
```

In this query `calculation_ID` is redundant (I use it only to make example clearer for code reader). But you still can apply this info to check integrity of logging data format, exploring if equal `calculation_ID` corresponds to the metrics involved in the same group/time-period.

Comment: @Lars Schneider, what do you think about this solution?